# Merge two dataframes but mean columns that exists in both

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, reshape2

Say I have two data.frames,

```
df = data.frame(gene = c("KRAS", "FOS"), A6 = c(20, 50), A7 = c(90, 80))
df2 = data.frame(gene = c("KRAS", "FOS"), A6 = c(20, 250) )
```

Here `A6` is repeated and when I try to merge these two dataframes, using `merge(df, df2, by = "gene")`), and it creates new columns with `A6.x` and `A6.y`.

Is there a way to have it merge such that it will instead take the mean of columns that are duplicated?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After `merge`ing `split` the data by the numeric column names (substring) and get the `rowMeans`

```
cbind(out[1], sapply(split.default(out[-1], 
          sub("\\..*", "", names(out)[-1])), rowMeans))
#  gene  A6 A7
#1  FOS 150 80
#2 KRAS  20 90
```

#### data

```
out <- merge (df, df2, by="gene")
```

Comment: what kind of wizardry is this? It works but don't understand it. It even works when I try to merge > 2 replicates.  Thank you.

Comment: @Ahdee The key is `split` the dataset into `list` of `data.frame`s based on the commonality of the column names.  Here, we removed the `.x` `.y` part with `sub`, so column names are the same to split.  Then, it just looping through the `list` (with `sapply`) and getting the row wise mean

Answer (score 3):

Since the desired `merge` in this example isn't adding any new columns to `df`, you could use a data.table update join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
setDT(df2)

df[df2, on = .(gene), A6 := (A6 + i.A6)/2]

df
#    gene  A6 A7
# 1: KRAS  20 90
# 2:  FOS 150 80
```

This will modify `df`. If you want a new dataframe, you can use `copy`

```
copy(df)[df2, on = .(gene), A6 := (A6 + i.A6)/2]
```

For multiple common columns

```
no.avg <- 'gene'
common <- intersect(names(df), names(df2))
common <- setdiff(common, no.avg)

df[df2, on = .(gene), 
   (common) := (get(common) + get(paste0('i.', common)))/2]
```

Comment: Nice ! Please, how do you deal with this in case there are many columns that are duplicated ?